# Raspberry Pi 3: OpenCV 3.4.0 missing some files after installation and can't be called within my code

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I hope you're doing good.

I've been working on a  robot for couple of months and got it working properly recently. 
Sadly, my code got deleted including all libraries, tried to install OpenCV couple of times but I'm still getting errors

I used this link to install OpenCV 3.4.0 with the latest version of Raspbian https://www.life2coding.com/install-opencv-3-4-0-python-3-raspberry-pi-3/

> ImportError: libavcodec.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Is there a proper way to install all libraries ? I'll include all libraries I used at the beginning of the code **below**.

Thanks in advance

```
   [import cv2
    import cv2.cv as cv
    import numpy as np
    from gopigo import *
    import sys
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    import os
    import multiprocessing as mp
```

Comment: I've added more information to the post, if I missed things up feel free to reply since I'm trying to describe the whole project and what issues I'm facing which couldn't be understandable to all user.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: yes, you're right and I understand your point. I thought that I have to get some explanation to the whole project before stating the problem, it's always good to get feedback from you people. 
Thanks and I'll try to figure it out soon.

Comment: You didn't explain what command you used to install the library? and what commend you use to execute the script. Are you running python2.x? or python3.x? I suspect that you install the library on one version and running the script on another version. What you see if you run `pip list` and `pip3 list`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've updated my question with the version of OpenCV which is 3.4.0 and link to the commands used to install the library

Comment: I'll check these links shortly, thanks for your help again I really appreciate it.

Comment: got it fixed :) thanks for your help Jayjayyy 
I've stated everything in a new comment below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using 'Raspbian Stretch Lite' but didn't work, I might have missed something up while installing OpenCV library

I tried latest version of 'Raspbian Stretch with desktop and recommended software' from Raspberrypi's website https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

and followed all steps stated here to install OpenCV https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/

Once done with OpenCV use this command within your code to relocate packages

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

OpenCV is working fine to me now. Thanks to J.D. and Jayjayyy for guiding me and helping me to solve this issue, I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you installed an old/wrong version of opencv, or it could be that you installed the base version, without the extra modules.

I would advice installing use pip, always works for me. In that case the following command should be enough:

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Note: you need to uninstall openCV first. Read more about the installation [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

If you dont know what pip is, read about it and install from [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, will try it asap and hope it gets fixed

Comment: I'm still having this error..tried to install using root user too 
ImportError: libavcodec.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I googled the error for you (step 1 when you run into troubles) and in the top hits where 2 threads about the exact same issue. OpenCV expects version 56 of libavcodec to be installed, but it seem your system has a newer version. Given solutions include: use older version of raspbian, install older version of libavcoded, install specific version of opencv or compile your own version of opencv. Check the threads for specifics: 1 - https://github.com/jabelone/OpenCV-for-Pi/issues/10 2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783047/how-to-install-libavformat-so-56-along-with-libavformat-so-57

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info, I'll consider this solution for sure and will give it a try.
Will pre-installed images with OpenCV installed work properly if I added couple of extra libraries to them?

Comment: got it fixed :) Thanks for your help and efforts J.D. 
I've stated everything I did in a new comment